# How to make the MaterializeCSS fixed-action-btn Toolbar into just a toolbar?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want to have a tool bar like the fixed-action-btn one in materializecss, but I just want it to be the tool bar I don't want it pop out of the button. Does anyone know how to do this?? Here is some code to explain.

```html
<footer>
  <div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
      <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, I'll keep up the question so that it can help others!

```
  <div class="toolbar-fixed red">
<ul>
  <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
  <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
  <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
  <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

```
    .toolbar-fixed {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 56px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.toolbar-fixed.active > a i {
opacity: 0;
}

.toolbar-fixed ul {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}


.toolbar-fixed ul li {
-webkit-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
display: inline-block;
margin: -;
height: 100%;
transition: none;
position: relative;
top: -15px;

}


.toolbar-fixed ul li a{
display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
   color: #fff;
  line-height: 56px;
  z-index: 1;
   }

.toolbar-fixed ul li a i {
line-height: inherit;
}

.toolbar-fixed ul {
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.toolbar-fixed ul li {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This was a good solution! Thanks!

One note, when placed inside a container it was positioned to the left of the container, not to the left of the screen. I had to add `left: 0px;`

```
.toolbar-fixed {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 56px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't able to find any *"official"* or documented way to do it, but here's a practical one:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  var rO = $('.renderOpen'),
      bF = rO.find('.btn-floating').first();
  bF.trigger('click');
  setTimeout(function(){
    rO.animate({opacity:1},{duration:400,delay:400},function(){
      rO.removeClass('renderOpen');
    })
  }, 270)
});
```

```css
.renderOpen { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<footer>
  <div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar renderOpen">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: did u found a way to put it always sticked at bottom?